# Modify jQuery UI slider control

Tags: jquery, user-interface, slider

I use the jQuery UI slider control. My slider has a width of `200px`. I would like the center of my left handle to be shifted `14px` right and the center of my right handle to be offset left by `14px`.

My slider will be more than `172px` (`200 -14 - 14`). The `background-image` measures `200px`. The length of `14px` is calculated as follows:

```
width of the handle (28px) / 2
```

I use `margin-left: 0px;` to delete the `margin-left:-14px` by default. But, my right handle moves `28px` to the right!

Can you help me solve this mystery?

```
.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle {
    width: 28px; 
    height: 28px; 
    background: url(http://hitskin.com/themes/13/67/44/i_right_arrow.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    overflow: hidden; 
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 0;
    top: -7px;
    border-style: none;
    cursor: help;
}​
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/3teR3/)

Comment: Any link to let us see whats going on?

Comment: http://www.celinni.com/creaprint/recherche00.php

Comment: Does this re-create the slider (sans image)? http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/3teR3/

Comment: To Jared Farrish. You see that your right handle bar spring the slide ...

Comment: @Jean-YvesDeman - Yes, I see that. The problem is that you're moving it to the right, but it still travels the same distance.

Comment: Yes I do. But it isn't no correct !

Comment: How so? Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange you want to change default style as the new style you are applying is quite ugly. Thats said, you can override special style for the right handle like that:

```
$(function(){
   $('.ui-slider a:nth-child(odd)').css('margin-left','-28px');
});
```

Comment: That's Ok for the first slider control. But for the other sliders control, it does not work

Comment: I don't think that solves the problem, since the `margin-left` is actually getting added. See: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/3teR3/2/ Oops, was trying to show the adjusted and "normal" sliders, but forget to take out the `margin-left` on the bottom "normal" one. Try it again.

Comment: I prefer to move the handles

Comment: Your second proposed solution does not work at all! Even for the first slider!

Comment: Super awesome! Thank you. I always post another post on the slider UI. Do you still want to help me,

Comment: Which post? By the way, help communauty by accepting this answer

Comment: And the left handle go to the right, for sure, this is because when modificate css margin, you are changing default behaviour, distance between two handles doesn't take into account these margins. You should then extend jquery ui slider range to fix it. BTW, STOP SPAMMING COMMENT, your last comment is so useless!

Comment: Know you tell me how to do this? Sorry for the spanning!

Comment: I do not see the property is to change the UI to get there to fix this bug. Before posting, I try with these css

Comment: @Jean-YvesDeman - Why are you manually shifting the right slider instead of changing the `values: [ 75, 375 ]`? And yea, that was suspect.

Comment: This is why I also wondered how reduced the useful range of 28px. What must change in UI ?

Comment: @Jean-YvesDeman - Oh. You made the slider handles wider, then tried to move them back by shifting back to the right. That's not how you would want to do that, though.

Comment: I wanted the useful range of 172px. Measure the width of the slider 200px

Comment: How so? Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

All of that, and the whole time it was just that you were using the wrong measure. You need to use `em`s instead of `px`s, which I figured out when I looked at the original size and `margin-left`. So...

```
.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle {
    height: 1.6em;
    width: 1.6em;
    margin-left: -.8em;
    position: absolute;
    top: -7px;
    background: url(http://www.celinni.com/creaprint/js/ui/images/bulle.png) no-repeat center center;
    border-style: none;
    cursor: help;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/3teR3/5/

I've made the images partially transparent (in Firefox or Chrome) so you can see that they're perfectly lined up. And when you slide them, they also work fine.

Comment: How to reduce a useful range?

Comment: What do you mean? How to calculate what you need? As long as the `margin-left` is equal to the negative of half the `width`, you're good. Also, your `top: -7px` should also be half the `height: 1.6em;` as well. Same concept. So http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/3teR3/6/